# how to submit a form from loaded form into main page?

Tags: javascript, php, contact-form

contact.php

```
... html form ...

$('#submit').click(function(){
$.post("mail.php", $("#contact").serialize(), function(response) {
$('#success').html(response);
});
return false;
});
```

mail.php is a separate file (for sending mail), and everything works in this arrangement.

**But I need to load contact.php into index.php**

```
$('#divR').load('chapters/contact.php');
```

so corresponding js line becomes

```
 $.post("chapters/mail.php", $("#contact").serialize(), function(response) {...
```

Submitting the form in this case `response` from `mail.php` is received, but `POST` array is empty, i.e. form doesn't send any data to `mail.php` !?

Comment: Are you sure the paths are correct? Does the code in `mail.php` and `contacts.php` behave correctly? If you have Firebug, you should check these things first.

Comment: @Broxzier, I think, in case path is wrong it could not be possible to receive response from `mail.php` (it says:you must fill all fields). Also, path is very simple, I'm sure it is correct. I have firebug, please, what I should check, on which tab. There is no error in console.

Comment: Under the Net tab you can see post and get request, and see what headers and data you send and receive. This data might be incorrect, since your JavaScript looks just fine.

Comment: @Broxzier, I checked `Post mail.php`. `Post` tab is empty, and in the `Response` tab there is just the response I received in the form. I have no idea. Could you please create two files `contact.php` with simple contact form and javascript code, and `mail.php` with php code for sending mail. Both files put in `chapters` folder.  `index.php` is in root. Then load `contact.php` into a div inside `index.php` and try to submit the form.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote your code in 2 new pages to see what it actually does, and noticed a few things. A few small things such as calling the submit handler instead of click, since people can also press Enter to submit a form, but most important the data itself: A form doesn't need to be serialized, the browser will already do that for you. In this script I store the data in a new object and pass it to the `$.post` method.

```
<form method="post" action="" id="contact">
    <div>
        <input id="email" type="text">
    </div>
    <div>
        <input id="submit" type="submit">
    </div>
</form>
```

Script:

```
$("#contact" ).on("submit", function () {
    var data = {
        email: $("#email").val()
    };

    $.post("test.php", data, function (response) {
        $('#success').html(response);
    });

    return false;
});
```

In `test.php` I simply do a `print_r($_POST)`, which is also the response. It will output something like:

```
Array
(
    [email] => test
)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Broxzier, try to load your form from another folder into index.php, and then submit it. It doesn't work. Everything works (both your and my code) if the form file is stand alone, but not if it is loaded.

Comment: @SunSky Oh, now I get what you're actually asking. You're loading the form via ajax or something, but the JavaScript on the new elements doesn't work. Please, let me know if I'm correct.

Answer (score 0):

I've made a simple test, trying to mimic your goal:
testLoad.php = index.php in your case:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
    $('#testLoad').load('Test/testForm.php');   
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="testLoad"></div>
<div id="success"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

testForm.php and testTarget.php are respectively - contact.php and mail.php and are situated in folder Test their code is as follows:
testForm.php:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<form id="contact" method="post" action="">
  <p>
    <label for="textfield">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="textfield" id="textfield">
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="textfield2">Address:</label>
    <input type="text" name="textfield2" id="textfield2">
</p>
  <p>
    <label for="textfield3">Mail:</label>
    <input type="text" name="textfield3" id="textfield3">
</p>
  <p>
    <label for="textfield4">Subject:</label>
    <input type="text" name="textfield4" id="textfield4">
    <br>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="textarea">Message:</label>
    <textarea name="textarea" id="textarea"></textarea>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" onClick="sendForm();">
  </p>
</form>
<script>
$('#submit').bind('click', function(){
        //console.log($("#contact").serialize());
        $.post("Test/testTarget.php", $("#contact").serialize(), function(response) {
            $('#success').html(response);
        });
        return false;
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

and testTarget.php :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php print_r($_POST);?>
</body>
</html>
```

when testing in success div I receive the POST printed out. 
Hope this helps.